# how to change the comma operator into semicolon in response

Tags: scripting, jmeter, execution

hi my response is having a list of values I can capture that but I need to pass those list with semicolon operator in my next request. how to do that in jmeter .

response is

user defined:

> { 1234, 4568, 7890 }

I have to pass those values in  my next request as 
user defined:

> { 1234; 4568; 7890 }

like this.

how do I can ? can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the 1st request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   vars.put('changedResponse',prev.getResponseDataAsString().replace(",",";"))
   ```

   where:

   - `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, it provides read/write access to JMeter Variables
   - `prev` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

So you will be able to access amended value where commas will be changed to semicolons as `${changedResponse}` where required.

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter tests

Comment: Dimitri , answer you give will work , but my response have a lot of data and we have lot of commas in that also . I need to change this particular part of my response only. { 1234, 4568, 7890 } . I think you understand my query.